# PHP input inside a while loop

Tags: php, mysqli, while-loop

I have wanted to loop a set of inputs according to the database inside a while loop. But I could not define the input name correctly which ended up in, the submitted POST being empty, when checked with var_dump($_POST).

```
<body background="images/tl.jpg">
<div id="container">    
    <?php include "mysql/head.php" ?>
    <div id="main">



<p align="left"> Your Staff ID : <?php echo $_SESSION['u_username'] ?></p>
<p align="left"> Your E-Mail : <?php echo $_SESSION['u_acemail']; ?></p>

<form id="sub-form" action="mysql/save_result.php/">
    <center>
<table align="center" width=80% border="2" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
<th>Student Index No</th>
<th>Result</th>


    <?php

    include "mysql/dbconnect.php";

        $batchno = $_POST['batch'] ;
        $year = $_POST['y'];
        $semester = $_POST['s'];
        $tname = $batchno."_".$year."_".$semester;
        $subcode = $_POST['subject'];

        $_SESSION['batchno'] = $_POST['batch'];
        $_SESSION['year'] =  $_POST['y'];
        $_SESSION['semester'] = $_POST['s'];
        $_SESSION['tname'] = $batchno."_".$year."_".$semester;
        $_SESSION['subcode'] = $_POST['subject'];


    echo "Results Table Name : ".$tname;
    echo "<br><br>";
    echo "<b>Subject Code : ".$subcode."&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;Batch : ".$batchno."&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;Year : ".$year."&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;Semester : ".$semester."</b><br>";

        $sql = "SELECT stindex,id FROM $tname WHERE stindex NOT LIKE '%stindex%' ORDER BY id;";

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $check = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

                $resultid = "result_".$row['id'];

                echo "<tr><td align='center'>".$row['stindex']."</td><td align='center'><input type='text' name='$resultid'>".$resultid."</td></tr>";
            }

            echo "</table><br>";
            echo "<b>Number of Rows Fetched :  ".$check."</b><br><br>";
    ?>
```

Submit Results

`

[image: This is whats in the page with only two "stindex"es in the database]

Comment: Please share your code, so we have something to look at, and discuss.

Comment: Please mention the comments for downvoting. Since the people are new they won't be able to know it. I am upvoting the question since the snippet has been added.

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS I also upvoted. Regretably downvoting is often a hit-and-run incident. Downvoters seldom comment, and even rarer revisit the question after a while. The best thing to do is to read up on how to ask a question, and get it correct.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Correct ! thanks for the upvote. Happy Coding :)

Comment: I don't see your form action and method so i'm not sure what is cause blank post. so can you please show us code with form tag open and close form tag?

Comment: @William Gunawan Oops.. sorry.. I just thought of shortning the post body and forgot that. Will do.

Comment: FYI : The NOT LIKE operator in the $sql query is for excluding the row with "names of columns" (which contain the subject codes), which was used to create the Header Row in the table used to view the Grades when the students are logged in.